# How to Create hyperlink to cell value in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, hyperlink, datatables, dt

I have a data frame `data_input` with the following content:

[image]

The dataframe is loaded in R shiny datatable with the below code:

```
output$table <-
DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(data_input,
  options = list(
    searching = TRUE,
    pageLength = 10,
    rownames(NULL),
    scrollX = T,
   filter="top"
  )
))
```

I would need to open a hyperlink. Upon clicking the value in the column **"Feature"**,  the value of the column **Location** should be appended to the url and direct to the corresponding page. For example, upon clicking `X` should direct to `http://www.mywebsite.com;loc=1:02` where `http://www.mywebsite.com;loc=` is common url to all values.

Any efficient ways to do this? there are similar threads however, the solutions are not concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.

```
library(DT)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var a = '<a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com?loc=' + row[2] + '\">' + data + '</a>';",
  "    return a;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

data_input <- data.frame(
  List = c("A", "B", "C"), 
  Feature = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
  Location = c("1:02", "2:04", "5:10")
)

datatable(data_input, rownames = FALSE, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 1, render = JS(render)),
              list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
            )
          )
)
```