# Hyperlink to cell value in R shiny (with many columns)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to generate hyperlinks from my datatable values. I've found this solution [How to Create hyperlink to cell value in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397770/how-to-create-hyperlink-to-cell-value-in-r-shiny)
and was perfect but was for just one column. Now I need also an alternative where hyperlinks are in every columns. Putting `targets = "_all"` in `columnDefs`, made hyperlink in each cell, but my problem is that if I click on that cell value (for example on `LPE(18:1)`), the generated link is composed of every value on that row. I think the solution is to pass the row and column index to the render function, but I have no idea how to do it. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)


data_input <- data.frame(
  List = c("Cer(d18:1/16:0)", "DGDG(16:0/18:0)", "PS(18:0/18:1)"), 
  Feature = c("LPE(18:1)", "LPE(20:4)",NA ),
  Location = c("MGDG(16:0/18:0)", "MGDG(18:0/18:0)" , "TG(18:1/18:1/18:1)")
)

render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var a = '<a href=\"http://www.swisslipids.org/#/search/' + row + '\">' + data + '</a>';",
  "    return a;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)



ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Table with Links!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Click the link in the table to go to the url listed.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('table1')
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data_input, rownames = T, 
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(targets = "_all", render = JS(render)),
                  list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
                )
              )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Furthermore, by default if a cell value is NA, that cell in the datatable will be blank, but in this case it's written `null` and has also an hyperlink. Is there a solution to not generate hyperlink for those cells? I just want that they remain blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stéphane Laurent will know better than me, but you could try this as your JS renderer. You can check if `data` is NULL if your `if` statement, and probably should include `data` in your hyperlink reference instead of "row". Try this out and and let me know if this helps.

```
render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display' && data){",
  "    var a = '<a href=\"http://www.swisslipids.org/#/search/' + data + '\">' + data + '</a>';",
  "    return a;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
```

**Edit**: If you have "Cer(d18:1_16:0)+OH" as an entry in a cell, but want to use "Cer(d18:1/16:0)" in your link, you could use the `replace` function and chain them for multiple replacements. In this case use /g for global modifier. You can adjust the regex for your particular needs.

```
render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display' && data){",
  "    var newstr = data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\\).*/g, ')');",
  "    var a = '<a href=\"http://www.swisslipids.org/#/search/' + newstr + '\">' + data + '</a>';",
  "    return a;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
```

Comment: The last question.  Is there a way to show in the table "LPE(18:1)" but when I generate the link, the lipid is edited? Like "LPE(18:1)+OH". So my idea is using `gsub()` but only for the "data" used for the link. I think I should add a `gsub()` inside the `render` function but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I think a lot depends on exactly what you want to do with your string for different cases. In your example, you are just adding "+OH" - which is easy to include in the `href` without anything special. However, if you have a regex pattern to use to modify `data` in the `href` you could try using `replace`. Again, it depends on exactly what changes between different lipid scenarios. If you edit your original post with a few examples of changes, I can take a look. Or, you could post a separate question on SO too.

Comment: Ok so there isn't a general solution. Anyway, what I have to do is pretty simple. I have lipids written like "Cer(d18:1_16:0)+OH" and the edited lipid (used only to generate the link) should be something like this "Cer(d18:1/16:0)". I need just two `gsub()` in order to do that:  `temp = gsub(").*", ")", data_input)` and `temp = gsub("_", "/", temp)`. How can I put these gsubs inside the render function?

Comment: @FabioDR See edited answer and let me know if this helps. You can use `replace` in javascript for this and include regex patterns that meet your needs.